# How to replace the lens on a Nikon Coolpix P7000 with a new lens assembly?

Tags: nikon, repair, diy

[image]

I have a Nikon Coolpix P7000 with the dreaded lens cover problem. (i.e. the cover did not fully open causing shadows in the corners of the pictures.)
I have purchased a new lens assembly and stared to remove the old lens, however on disassembly, I have gotten as far as the main board but I cannot see how to remove the optical viewer assembly. I am also wondering how I remove the front cover, and if that is a step I need to take.

Comment: Sometimes things are held in by the other items around it. Try removing other items from the camera. You never know you might find a hidden screw or something!

Comment: Did you have a hard time with the rest of the assembly? I just ordered a new lens unit and wondering if there's something I should know when I attempt the repair.

Answer (score 2):

right side of the optical viewer, there is a screw hole, between two of them, there is a gap, looking through over, there is one more screw in the bottom side there, tricky one, good luck.

[image]